# StackExchange.Redis Lazy connection configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, stackexchange.redis

I'am trying to implement Redis cache service by StackExchange.Redis library.

My Redis client:

```
public class RedisClient
    {
        private static Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> lazyConnection = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() =>
        {
            return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(string.Format("{0},{1}",
                        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.GetStringOrDefault("redis_masters", "someIP1:6379"),
                        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.GetStringOrDefault("redis_slaves", "someIP2:6379")));
        });

        public static ConnectionMultiplexer GetConnection
        {
            get
            {
                return lazyConnection.Value;
            }
        }
    }
```

And i try to get connection in this way:

```
using (var redis = RedisClient.GetConnection)
{
    ...
}
```

I get exception: *"It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s); to create a disconnected multiplexer, disable AbortOnConnectFail. UnableToResolvePhysicalConnection on PING"*

I also tried to add some configuration to connection like this:

```
ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(string.Format("{0},{1},Ssl=false"
```

And i get another exception: *"ValueFactory attempted to access the Value property of this instance."*

My connection to Redis worked fine with enother library : `"StackExchange.Redis"`
I just try to migrate is to `"ServiceStack.Redis"`
What i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use password in configuration

```
ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost,password=XXXXX");
```